# Laravel request get all filled values

Tags: php, laravel

I am checking each field in laravel request like:

```
if($request->filled('type'))
    $item->type = $request->get('type');
```

Like `$request->all()` gives all the inputs in an array, Can we get all the filled values only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on the results which will provide just the non-empty values:

```
$results = array_filter($request->all());
```

Note that if 0 is valid, you might have to use a callback instead.

```
$results = array_filter($request->all(), 'strlen');
```

Comment: Yeah, 0 is a valid input data. Second one is working fine. Thanks...